# Finding a current on a RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor, parallel

I'm studying all by myself, I'm not taking any courses or majoring at something. Last year I had a question about an RL circuit that's been annoying me for a while. Now I'm at home doing nothing but reviewing some exercises that I've already done and this one is a problem, as I couldn't do this one.

The question is: How can find \$i_3(t)\$, that little current right through that inductor?

[image: diagram]

PS: If you just give me a little start, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: Heres a hint, the current and voltage behave in the opposite way to an RC circuit

Comment: Initially, the switch is open. So the initial current through the 4H inductor is zero. And the 7H was connected for a long time. So it's in short circuit condition initially. These are initial conditions. Try to find the final (i.e. steady-state) condition after the switch is pressed.

Comment: Thank you all!  I found i3(0) and i3(inf), but I think that the problem is the time constant. It is L/R = 4/(what?)
By the way, I had the final answer, but I just can't do it from the start.

I've got:  0.25 + (0 - 0.25)exp^-(t/time const)